# trying witness null: result of operation might violate subset type constraint

Tags: dafny

I've written a class that represents a binary relation on a set, S, with two fields: that set, S, and a second set of pairs of values drawn from S. The class defines a bunch of properties of relations, such as being single-valued (i.e., being a function, as defined in an "isFunction()" predicate). After the class definition I try to define some subset types. One is meant to define a subtype of these relations that are also actually "functions". It's not working, and it's a bit hard to decode the resulting error codes. Note that the Valid() and isFunction() predicates do declare "reads this;". Any ideas on where I should be looking? Is it that Dafny can't tell that the subset type is inhabited? Is there way to convince it that it is?

```
    type func<T> = f: binRelOnS<T> | f.Valid() && f.isFunction()
```

[Dafny VSCode] trying witness null: result of operation might violate subset type constraint for 'binRelOnS'

Comment: In modern Dafny, class names refer to the non-null variant of the class. You can say `binRelOn?` to allow the possibility of null. Unfortunately I don't think there's any other way to construct a witness.

Comment: When I add ? (i.e., when I use binRelOnS? as the base type) Dafny complains with this: "cannot find witness that shows type is inhabited (only tried null); try giving a hint through a 'witness' or 'ghost witness' clause". I find no documentation on the witness and/or ghost witness clause concept (only two hits on Google). Would be happy to provide more context if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

### Subset types and non-emptiness

A subset type definition of the form

```
type MySubset = x: BaseType | RHS(x)
```

introduces `MySubset` as a type that stands for those values `x` of type `BaseType` that satisfy the boolean expression `RHS(x)`. Since every type in Dafny must be nonempty, there is a proof obligation to show that the type you declared has some member. Dafny may find some candidate values and will try to see if any one of them satisfies `RHS`. If the candidates don't, you get an error message like the one you saw. Sometimes, the error message will tell you which candidate values Dafny tried.

In your case, the only candidate value that Dafny tried is the value `null`. As James points out, the value `null` doesn't even get to first base, because the `BaseType` in your example is a type of non-null references. If you change `binRelOnS<T>` to `binRelOnS?<T>`, then `null` stands a chance of being a possible witness for showing your subset type to be nonempty.

### User-supplied witnesses

Since Dafny is not too clever about coming up with candidate witnesses, you may have to supply one yourself. You do this by adding a `witness` clause at the end of the declaration. For example:

```
type OddInt = x: int | x % 2 == 1 witness 73
```

Since `73` satisfies the RHS constraint `x % 2 == 1`, Dafny accepts this type. In some programs, it can happen that the witness you have in mind is available only in ghost code. You can then write `ghost witness` instead of `witness`, which allows the subsequent expression to be ghost. A ghost witness can be used to convince the Dafny verifier that a type is nonempty, but it does not help the Dafny compiler in initializing variables of that type, so you will still need to initialize such variables yourself.

Using a `witness` clause, you could attempt to supply your own witness using your original definition of the subset type `func`. However, a witness clause takes an expression, not a statement, which means you are not able to use `new`. If you don't care about compiling your program and you're willing to trust yourself about the existence of the witness, you can declare a body-less function that promises to return a suitable witness:

```
type MySubset = x: BaseType | RHS(x) ghost witness MySubsetWitness()

function MySubsetWitness(): BaseType
  ensures RHS(MySubsetWitness())
```

You'll either need `ghost witness` or `function method`. The function `MySubsetWitness` will forever be left without a body, so there's room for you to make a mistake about some value satisfying `RHS`.

The `witness` clause was introduced in Dafny version 2.0.0. The [2.0.0 release notes](https://github.com/Microsoft/dafny/releases/tag/v2.0.0) mention this, but apparently don't give much of an explanation. If you want to see more examples of `witness`, search for that keyword in the [Dafny test suite](https://github.com/Microsoft/dafny/tree/master/Test).

### Subset types of classes

In your example, if you change the base type to be a possibly-null reference type:

```
type func<T> = f: binRelOnS?<T> | f.Valid() && f.isFunction()
```

then your next problem will be that the RHS dereferences `f`. You can fix this by weakening your subset-type constraint as follows:

```
type func<T> = f: binRelOnS?<T> | f != null ==> f.Valid() && f.isFunction()
```

Now comes the part that may be a deal breaker. Subset types cannot depend on mutable state. This is because types are a very static notion (unlike specifications, which often depend on the state). It would be a disaster if a value could satisfy a type one moment and then, after some state change in the program, not satisfy the type. (Indeed, almost all type systems with subset/refinement/dependent types are for functional languages.) So, if your `Valid` or `isFunction` predicates have a `reads` clause, then you cannot define `func` in the way you have hoped. But, as long as both `Valid` and `isFunction` depend only on the values of `const` fields in the class, then no `reads` clause is needed and you are all set.

Rustan